# Pyvmomi API _mor.TerminateVM throws pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.NotSupported: (vmodl.fault.NotSupported)

Tags: python, pyvmomi

I am trying to power off a VM hosted on ESX host.
while host _mor.TerminateVM is executed below exception is thrown.

```
pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.NotSupported: (vmodl.fault.NotSupported) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = 'The operation is not supported on the object.',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) []
```

On exploring, I found this.
https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/723e7f8b-4f21-448b-a830-5f22fd931b01/5a8257bd-7f41-4423-9a73-03307535bd42/doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html#terminate

Kindly help me in setting VirtualMachine.Interact.PowerOff privilege on HOST.

Comment: What is the context here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to power off the VM by making below API call on host managed object reference and getting vmodl.fault.NotSupported exception.
https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/723e7f8b-4f21-448b-a830-5f22fd931b01/5a8257bd-7f41-4423-9a73-03307535bd42/doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html#terminate

I suspect it might be due to missing privilege, thus want to add that privilege before making this call.

Comment: vm.TerminateVM() using pyvmomi is what I am trying to do.. any help ?